# Find the orthonormal vectors $q_{1}, q_{2}, q_{3}$ such that $q_{1}, q_{2}$ span the column space of $A$?

Tags: orthonormal, orthogonality, span

We have given the matrix

$$ A= \begin{pmatrix} 1 &1 \\ 2& -1 \\ -2 & 4 \end{pmatrix}$$

First the question asks find the orthonormal vectors $q_{1}, q_{2}, q_{3}$ such that $q_{1}, q_{2}$ span the column space of $A$?
Then the question asks which of the fundamental subspaces of the matrix $A$ contains $q_{3}$?

I used Gram-Schmidt method to get $q_{1}$ and $q_{2}$ using the bases for this process as the column space of $A$. i.e Basis: $\{(1, 2, -2),(1, -1, 4)\}$. I got $q_{1}= \frac{1}{3}(1, 2, -2)$, $q_{2}=\frac{1}{3}(2, 1, 2)$.

**How do I find q3 and what fundamental subspace of the matrix contains it ?**

Comment: Are you sure it's not a typo in whatever question you're looking at?  The only thing I can think is that maybe they want orthonormal vectors that span $R^3$ such that $q_1$ and $q_2$ span the column space of $A$.  If so, take any vector outside the column space and put it into Gram Schmidt.  The result will be orthogonal to the column space of $A$.

Comment: To get braces {} in mathmode you can type type `\{` and `\}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complete $q_1,q_2$, to a basis in some way for example take $p$ some element of the canonical bases, and run Gram-Schmidt on $q_1,q_2,p$, to find $q_3$.

The third vector $q_3$ will be orthogonal to the space spanned by the columns. This means 
$$q_3^TA= 0$$

I cannot know how you should call the space of $x$ with $x^T A= 0$, common names include left null space and cokernel. But it is best to check your reference how it is called there as terminology is not completely uniform.

Comment: yes that is the left null space

Comment: So what i gather from you answer is that I will make a basis q3 = (p, p, p). I will perform Gram-Schmidt on these. All well so far, however I get q3 = p( x x x) where x is a number. This basis is in terms of p. This doesn't seem like much worth? 

(I also found the inner product of q3 with q2 and q1 since this should be equal to zero but again i get values in terms of p, which doesn't seem like much worth)

**In addition**,
I don't understand why q3 will be orthogonal to the space spanned by the columns as you said?

Comment: I said you could try to take $p$ some element of the canonical basis, so take $p=(1,0,0)$ for example. But you can take $p$ any *particular* vector indepedent of $q_1,q_2$, so you can also take it to equal $(1,1,1)$ if you want. For the second question: $q_3$ will be orthogonal to $q_1$ and $q_2$ and thus to the space spanned by $q_1,q_2$. Now recall that Gram-Schmidt preserves the space spanned by the first $k$ vectors, for each $k$. So the space spanned by $q_1,q_2$ is in fact the space spanned by the two columns.